# error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnTabSelectedListener> cannot be converted to BaseOnTabSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, material-components-android

After upgrade my library called

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
```

to latest version, Its giving me error like

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnTabSelectedListener> cannot be converted to BaseOnTabSelectedListener
```

my code in Fragment like this

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                                    }
                                });
```

Let me know if someone can help me for solve the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update and change setOnTabSelectedListener to addOnTabSelectedListener or use the below code

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite informative here.

You are creating an anonymous class of type `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` which **is not a** `BaseOnTabSelectedListener`, but `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener` expects a `BaseOnTabSelectedListener`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. I am beginner of android and java, can you please give me example code for same? Thanks